# How to send this Android device id to database using JSON?

Tags: android, json, uniqueidentifier

Do Android devices have a unique id, and if so, what is a simple way to access it via java?
How to send this Android device id  to database using JSON, Kindly Help me,Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Comment: You can use device IMEI number as device id...